# Kivymd and Requests Android Problem with "requests.get(url, cookies=cookie)" on some mobile 4g networks not working

Tags: python, android, python-requests, kivymd, 4g

I'm making an application with kivymd that includes authentication to a site using post and get requests with cookies. I'm encountering a problem that I haven't been able to resolve for more than a week, regarding the fact that on Android when you try to make a get request by also incorporating the session cookie it only succeeds if connected to WI-FI but on a mobile network 4g not on all, some yes, some no. While digging around I found that perhaps the problem is the "SSL" certificate. I tried to bypass this check by adding "verify=false" in my python code. Can anyone help me on how I can solve this problem?

I tried various ways including the urllib3 library but nothing changed, I installed a VPN and this also gave no results. When the request is not successful, always print the html login page instead of the html dashboard.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.